# r rda vegan ggplot geom_text. I wanna specify the label position to put it exactly where the arrows point

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan, geom-text, rda

This is what I want to put the text label to the position where the arrows point:

[image: This is what I want to put the text label to the position where the arrows point]

These are my results:

[image: results]

I want to put the text label to the position where the arrows point,
I used library(ggrepel).

My code is

```
  p <- ggplot(rda_tb_fs.site, aes(RDA1, RDA2)) +
       geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color = 'gray', size = 0.5) + 
       geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = 'gray', size = 0.5) +
       geom_segment(data = rda_tb_fs.env,
           aes(x = 0,y = 0, xend = RDA1,yend = RDA2), 
           arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.4, 'cm'),
                         angle=20,
                         type = "open"), 
           size = 1,
           lineend="round",
           linejoin="mitre",
           color='blue'
             ) +
       geom_text_repel(data = rda_tb_fs.env, 
                      aes(RDA1*1.06, RDA2 *1.05,
                          label=c("K","pH","ORP",
                                 "HCO3","WTO")
                        ))
```

I understand when RDA1 is positive then what I need is RDA1+0.1,but when RDA1 is negtive what i need is RDA1-0.1，i just don't known how to put this conditional statements into use.

[this is data 1 which i made some reforms under the principle of confidentiality](https://github.com/diewang96/data/blob/main/porewater.csv)

[data 2](https://github.com/diewang96/data/blob/main/RDA_T.csv)

[this is the original R code i wrote](https://github.com/diewang96/data/blob/main/RDA_ex.R)

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Hi, I just upload my data and the whole code,see the hyperlinks at the end of the article,thank you !

Comment: My understanding of ggrepel is that it is specifically designed *not* to put the text in  the coordinates you give, but to *repel* text "away from each other and away from the data points". geom_text would put text exactly where you want. Having text exactly at the position _pointed to_ by the arrow needs a bit more computing. vegan:::ordiArrowTextXY shows how to do this in conventional R graphics. Trickier in ggplot2, and ggvegan2::geom_ordiarrow  (in github) just defaults to geom_text with vjust="outwards", hjust="outwards".

Comment: Hi,you just inspired me. geom_text_repel(aes( ) ) can adjustify text position .what i need is  a little bit calculation which i just figure out. And i change geom_text_ggrepel() back to geom_text(), thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I changed change geom_text_ggrepel() back to geom_text(),and made some modification in geom_text(aes()) and it works:

```
  geom_text(data = rda_tb_fs.sp, 
        aes(
        ((RDA1^2+RDA2^2)^0.5+0.15)/(RDA1^2+RDA2^2)^0.5*RDA1, 
        ((RDA1^2+RDA2^2)^0.5+0.15)/(RDA1^2+RDA2^2)^0.5*RDA2,
            label=c("Cd","Cr","Zn","Ni",
                    "Cu","Pb","Co","Fe",
                    "Mn","As","Ti"
                    )
        ),
        size =5,
        fontface = "bold",
        family="Times New Roman",
        color='red',
        parse = T,
        )
```

[this is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoxG6.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).